# When to check if a query completed successfully

Tags: php, mysql

When do you want to check to see if a query completed successfully? Often in code I see a mixed bag of either checking if a update/insert/delete statement completed successfully (e.g. `if ($query) { echo 'success' }` or no checking at all.

I googled to see what the recommended choice was, but didn't find any relevant results. Further, I also realize this question is quite subjective depending on how sensitive the data is. But at the same time, unless the coder made a seriously malformed query to begin with, what is the point of checking if a query completed?

```
if ($user->update_user($this->input->input_stream(), $info) === false) {
    encode_response('error', $this->n_config->get('query_error'));
} else {
    encode_response('success', Auth_lang::get('user_updated_successfully'));
}
```

Comment: A) Use exceptions so you can't forget to test for errors. B) Try and return logically true values from functions to indicate succes. C) Avoid comparisons like `=== false` when simple negation would work. D) Don't set up double-negative conditions, like how this `else` represents "if update didn't not succeed".

Comment: @tadman what does that have to do with my question?

Comment: Do you need a long-form version of the same thing? The code is different because some people are lazy and don't take the time to do things correctly. If you presume the query succeeds, in a lot of cases you might be right and the code "works". It's when things go wrong you'll have no idea what malfunctioned unless you test every single query's result code. Hence: Use exceptions.

Comment: So you are saying it is *always* a good idea to check if a query returns true rather than just *assume* it does because it should? i mean it makes sense, I was just hoping for perhaps a guideline as to whether it is always necessary. out of curiosity do you always check? also do you use exceptions for everything, or just critical things? i read its best to only use them for 'exceptional' circumstances on this site

Comment: Is it always necessary? No. Is it always a good idea? Yes. What @tadman is recommending is to enable exception error mode via `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` -- see [this page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) for how to do that. If you do this, then you never have to explicitly check every query because errors will automatically throw exceptions. (Not sure offhand if there's an equivalent for the mysqli driver, I've never used it.)

Comment: Yep, there is, see `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php)

Answer (score 2):

Always. *Always.* **Always** check for errors. You cannot presume that one query has succeeded and then blindly stumble on to the next step or bad things will eventually happen.

The easiest way to check for errors is to have everything automatically checked: Enable exceptions. These will be fired if there's a problem, you won't have to manually check on each call. You will, however, have to figure out how and where to `catch` these so they don't blow up your whole application.

Programmers come from different backgrounds and have differing opinions on how to do these things, and some are just too lazy to bother doing them at all. In C code there's no such thing as exceptions, so those sorts of developers are used to testing for error codes. In Java exceptions are such an embedded part of the ecosystem they're a given and people use them judiciously.

PHP isn't sure what kind of a programming language it is, you can use exceptions *if you want to* and error codes if that's more your style. This is why you see an unusually high level of diversity in approaches to these things.